# How can i close the Action menu when one clicks outside the component anywhere

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i have an component to edit a table data what i want is when i click anywhere outside that component that component must be closed so what i have done till mow is as below

this is my parent component in which i have used that edit modal to show when click on it

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

import ActionMenu from './ActionMenu';

export default function DashBoard(props) {

    const columns = [
        {
            Header: 'Name',
            accessor: 'patient.name',
            Cell: (props) => <TextSpan>{props.value}</TextSpan>,
        },
        {
            Header: 'Time of Appointment',
            accessor: 'datetime',
            Cell: (props) => (
                <span>{moment(props.value).format('hh:mm A')}</span>
            ),
        },
        {
            Header: 'Actions',
            Cell: ({ row }) => (
                <ActionMenu
                    {...props}
                    handleAction={handleAction}
                    row={row.original}
                />
            ),
        },
    ];

    const handleAction = (value) => {
        changeAppointment(value).then((result) => {
            const newData = Array.from(data);

            const matchedIndex = newData.findIndex(
                (x) => x.id == result.data.id
            );
            newData[matchedIndex].status = result.data.status;

            setData(newData);
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        debounceSearch(search);
    }, [search]);
}
```

and this is my child component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import PostPone from 'Components/Modal';

export default function ActionMenu(props) {
    const { row, handleAction } = props;

    const [IsMenuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false);

    const [time, setTime] = useState(null);

    const [isModalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);

    return (
        <MainDiv>
            <ActionDiv>
                {row.status.toLowerCase() === 'confirmed' ? (
                    <ActionItem noPaddingLeft title="Come Now">
                        <ComeNow
                            onClick={() =>
                                handleAction({ id: row.id, status: 'inside' })
                            }
                        />
                    </ActionItem>
                ) : row.status.toLowerCase() === 'inside' ? (
                    <ActionItem noPaddingLeft title="Mark as visited">
                        <Approved
                            onClick={() =>
                                handleAction({ id: row.id, status: 'visited' })
                            }
                        />
                    </ActionItem>
                ) : (
                    <ActionItem>{<EmptyDiv />}</ActionItem>
                )}

                <ActionItem title={'Send Notification'}>
                    <SendNotification />
                </ActionItem>
                <ActionItem
                    title="Menu"
                    background
                    open={IsMenuOpen}
                    onClick={() => setMenuOpen(!IsMenuOpen)}
                >
                    <Dots />
                    {IsMenuOpen && (
                        <Menu>
                            <MenuItem
                                onClick={() =>
                                    props.history.push(
                                        '/appointments/edit_appointment?id=' +
                                            row.id
                                    )
                                }
                            >
                                <ItemLogo>
                                    <Edit />
                                </ItemLogo>
                                <ItemText>Edit</ItemText>
                            </MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem
                                borderBottom
                                paddingBottom
                                onClick={() =>
                                    handleAction({
                                        id: row.id,
                                        status: 'denied',
                                    })
                                }
                            >
                                <ItemLogo>
                                    <Close />
                                </ItemLogo>
                                <ItemText>Cancel</ItemText>
                            </MenuItem>

                            <MenuItem borderBottom paddingBottom paddingTop>
                                <ItemLogo>
                                    <Delay />
                                </ItemLogo>
                                <ItemText>Delay</ItemText>
                            </MenuItem>         
                            <MenuItem
                                paddingTop
                                onClick={() =>
                                    handleAction({
                                        id: row.id,
                                        status: 'inside',
                                    })
                                }
                            >
                                <ItemLogo>
                                    <ComeNowSmall />
                                </ItemLogo>
                                <ItemText>Come Now</ItemText>
                            </MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem
                                onClick={() =>
                                    handleAction({
                                        id: row.id,
                                        status: 'visited',
                                    })
                                }
                            >
                                <ItemLogo>
                                    <MarkVisted />
                                </ItemLogo>
                                <ItemText>Mark as Visited</ItemText>
                            </MenuItem>
                        </Menu>
                    )}
                </ActionItem>
            </ActionDiv>
        </MainDiv>
    );
}
```

[image]

as in image when i click on outside the child component it should close that component any help would be much appreciated thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use small trick.

You can render div with transparent background with absolute position under your overlay(DropDown). There you can handle click and close your overlay(DropDown).

Answer (score 1):

You need to check what is the element on click event, and if it's not your menu you can execute the close action.

Look this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/outside-alerter-hooks-lmr2y?module=/src/OutsideAlerter.js&file=/src/OutsideAlerter.js).